# Saving best Keras model based on mutiple parameters

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to use the ModelCheckpoint module in Keras with the monitor parameter having more than one option?. I want to save whenever validation accuracy increases. In case two models have the same validation accuracy, I want the one with the best training accuracy to be saved instead. Is this possible? If not, is there a way I can combine two different metrics using a harmonic average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a custom callback. Have a look at what ModelCheckpoint [does](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/bf1378f39d02b7d0b53ece5458f9275ac8208046/keras/callbacks.py#L421) and something along the lines of:

```python
class MyCheckpoint(Callback):
  # __init__ etc...
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    logs = logs or dict()
    acc = logs.get('acc')
    val_acc = logs.get('val_acc')
    # Your conditions
    if val_acc > self.best_val_acc:
      self.model.save_weights(filename)
      self.best_val_acc = val_acc
    elif val_acc == self.best_val_acc and acc > self.best_acc:
      self.model.save_weights(filename)
      self.best_acc = acc
```